# Why to choose or Why choose?

Tags: american-english

I'm not a native English speaker so I need your help on this one. When talking about a company, which one is correct:

1)Why to choose Google
2)Why choose Google?

For a non native speaker...why to choose sounds so strange but I've seen it written on a technology website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both are correct and identical; there is ellipsis at work in the second.

Comment: I agree that the first sounds very strange. From what I gather the first is strictly "This is why you should choose A" statement and second can be either that or "why did you choose A?" question

Answer (score 0):

natively speaking, i think -

1)Why to choose Google - is a statement and the reader assumes you already know the answer

2)Why choose Google - is a question

And i agree with  @Raestloz, try restructuring (with the risk of lengthening) (1) to "Why you should choose Google"

Comment: How about `Why choosing Google`?